# Migration of PrimeFaces from version x a newer version

Tags: primefaces, migration

Is there any guide on migrating / updating / upgrading PrimeFaces from 7.0 to the latest 8 version?

I am using the PrimeFaces Sapphire template, which works fine with PrimeFaces 7.0. But on migrating to latest 8 version, I have compilation problems concerning the PrimeFaces `UploadedFile` model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes the migration guide: https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/11_0_0/#/../migrationguide/migrationguide

Has changes and migration from every single version so look from where you are starting to where you are going. Don't be put off by the first version in the URL. For example the guide for 7.0 -> 8.0 can be found there as well: https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/11_0_0/#/../migrationguide/8_0